# how to input special character "," on sqlite android?

Tags: android, sqlite

i have script for insert multiple rows :

```
protected static final String INSERT_NAME_LIST1 = "insert into Table_Name(name1,name2) VALUES (1,'aa'),(1,'bb'),(1,'cc');";
```

But i have error :

```
06-21 14:15:31.155: E/AndroidRuntime(12798): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "','": syntax error: insert into Table_Name(name1,name2) VALUES (1,'aa')',' (1,'bb')',' (1,'cc');
```

please help me, how to fixed error ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can only have one set on values in the statement

```
protected static final String INSERT_NAME_LIST1 = "insert into Table_Name(name1,name2) VALUES (1,'aa');";
```

Multiple inserts can be done with a union

```
 INSERT INTO 'Table_Name'
 SELECT 1 AS 'name1', 'a' AS 'name2'
 UNION SELECT 2, 'b'
 UNION SELECT 3, 'c'
 UNION SELECT 4, 'd'
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it easily in noramally in SQL but in SQLite I think can try this in which it recast into sqlite as:

[Is it possible to insert multiple rows at a time in an SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database)